# styling for span inside anchor tag on Focus

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I am trying to style a text inside a `span` which is inside an anchor tag on focus.

On focus the text should receive an `underline`. the focus needs to be achieved through tabbing.

But its not working.

Could someone please take look and let me know what am missing

```css
body > div.afterLink > a > span:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="beforeLink">
  <span tabIndex=-1>Go to Google</span>
</div>
<div class="titleLink">
  <a class="download" target="_blank" href="www.google.com" title="Click here">
    <span>Go to Google</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="afterLink">
  <a class="download" target="_blank" href="www.google.com" title="Click here">
    <span>Go to Google</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aslums/mj134bvn/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `:focus` in `a` instead

```css
div.afterLink > a:focus > span {
  border-bottom: 10px solid green
}
```

```html
<div class="beforeLink">
  <span tabIndex=-1>Go to Google</span>
</div>
<div class="titleLink">
  <a class="download" target="_blank" href="www.google.com" title="Click here">
    <span>Go to Google</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="afterLink">
  <a class="download" target="_blank" href="www.google.com" title="Click here">
    <span>Go to Google</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Span elements cannot be focused (unless they have a tabindex attribute). Place the :focus selector on the anchor instead:

```css
body > div.afterLink > a:focus > span {
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="beforeLink">
  <span tabIndex=-1>Go to Google</span>
</div>
<div class="titleLink">
  <a class="download" target="_blank" href="www.google.com" title="Click here">
    <span>Go to Google</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="afterLink">
  <a class="download" target="_blank" href="www.google.com" title="Click here">
    <span>Go to Google</span>
  </a>
</div>
```